# Is the Matlab function 'quad' available in Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, matlab

I'm trying to port a Matlab code to Java and C++.
It's quite straightforward however I find a function that is more than simple operations, it numerically evaluates integral:

```
lungh=quad('normpp',0,1,[],[],x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7);
```

Here `x1,...,x8` and `y1,...,y7` are simple numbers.
First of all, how do this parameters are interpreted? How does this function work?

I think that 0 and 1 are the bounds of the integral...but what about the others?? Especially `'normpp'` and `[]`?

I read the `quad help` but I didn't understand how it works with such an amount of parameters.

The second problem is: Do exist a java and a C++ libraries that offer these function?
I would prefer to do it directly in Java and C++ without calling Matlab.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding you first question: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html

Comment: This has links to a number of implementations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: @PaulManta Thanks, I did it before however I didn't understand the meaning of all the parameters I report in the fucntion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C there is a very nice library : The Gnu Scientific Library (GSL).
Here is a link to the Numerical integration page of the GSL :
[GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-Integration.html)

The use of this library in a C++ project is straight forward.
I think the function gsl_integration_qag is a good choice to replace the matlab quad function.